# RStudio Quarto document not displaying in View pane

Tags: rstudio, quarto

Environment:

- Windows 10 Enterprise
- RStudio 2022.02.3 Build 492
- Quarto 0.9.629

When I try to render any Quarto html file (include the default file) with the "Preview in Viewer Pane" option selected, the viewer pane returns the message "Internal server error." I've confirmed that the file is created.

When I knit an RMarkdown html file with the "Preview in Viewer Pane" option selected, the viewer pane correctly returns the output.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: Same problem here too. I suspect this is related to the Windows security policy, which might block the internal RStudio web preview server.

Comment: The indicated versions of Quarto and RStudio are old - a preview release of Quarto and the release of RStudio before it fully supported all of Quarto. Please upgrade to the latest version of RStudio. If the issue persists you can open an issue/comment at: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions